# restriction of Gitflow release branch in team

Tags: git, git-flow

I am excited to find an comprehansive answer about my quastion. Here is it:

In my team we are using gitflow as a workflow to develop and release our projects. Now we are having a conceptial problem with gitflow.

When we decide to release, we push our work to release branch, where the QA and the customer test the code and response with a set of bugs or change requests of the current feature (No new feature as gitflow suggest).

The problem is when we want to fix bugs, as we need to work as team, many people should work on the same release branch. Therefore, either we are facing conflict problem through working togather or we have to work consequential which is not efficient to do the job.

We had the idea of creating new branches from release and working parallel on these branches, but we still feel that this is not the best way to do that.

What is the best way to let a team work parallel on a release branch to fix bugs?

Answer (score 0):

There's obviously no right or wrong here, but I suggest that you let QA & customer test feature branches independently. That way the scope of each testing session will be much smaller and easier to handle, and you can fix any problems without conflicting with other branches. Once your branch has been tested and fixed, you can move it to the release branch.

Comment: Thanks Emil for your answer. You are completly right, there's no wrong or right. We are working now in customize the workflow in order to make it fit in our team. Maybe it is a good idea to make QA testing on the feature branches, which reduce the future possible bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but for me an important part of the git flow methodology is that *everything* is branched and merged (via some sort of review process/pull request).

For this reason, I'd definitely recommend that you branch off your release branch and merge back into it. One obvious con from not branching is that you don't have a step to implement a review (like a pull request) without someone doing a fetch and check, at which point the commit is already in your release branch (bad!). Also, you could have two people commit and push at once, etc etc.

Having said that I know that this may not fit completely with the git flow process in that features and bugfixes are branched from `develop`, releases from `develop` and hotfixes from `master`, but you should also keep in mind that git flow is really just a concept, a guide and a mindset to adapt. The command line tools for it are just to help you out.

For example, at my current job we started trying to use git flow in its purity (and we have a similar sounding scenario to you) and found we ended up using the concepts but managing the branching ourselves and the merging in GitHub pull requests rather than your standard `git flow feature finish` type scenario. The main reason we did this is *to avoid multiple developers finishing and pushing a feature at the same time*.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Robbie for your answer. We actually having the same methodology as your team, becasue we never use gitflow as it is, since it does not fit 100% with our internal policy, e.g. nobody is allowed to push in develop only one person in the team is actually allowed to approve a PR to develop after checking and testing the PR. This leads us to the problem on the release branch, since we become about 30-40 bugs and change requests per week per project. So the release manager does not find time to tests all this PR and approve it. can I ask, who does approve the PR in you team?

Comment: We all approve each other's pull requests, whoever has time really

Comment: So maybe we have to think of improving our internal policy and start making it more flexible. :)

Comment: You could improve automated test coverage to ensure bug fix patches do what they should and don't break other areas